# My PC doesn't shut down with ubuntu 17.10

Tags: shutdown

When I updated to Ubuntu 17.10 it takes a long time to shut down..

Pressing esc on shut down it shows:

A stop job is running for Network name resolution

and after

A stop job is running for WPA supplicant

A stop job is running for Raise network interfaces

A stop job is running for Network Manager

These keep repeating for a very long time. What can I do to shut down faster?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your computer?

Answer (score 2):

Modify line in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` to `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=4s`. It will wait for stop job to finish in 4s.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem in the last few days, and this it helped me to shut down my laptop normally.